# Google Charts Treemap - How to change font size for Responsive Web Design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I have a google charts treemap responding well to change in resolution. It resizes and renders again with new size. Here's the resize code

```
function resize() {
      var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      tree.draw(data, {
        headerHeight: 15,
        fontColor: 'white',
        showScale: true});
      }

      window.onload = resize();
      window.onresize = resize;
    }
```

I would like to have the font size change based on change in resolution. So I would like to chart to have a larger font for smaller resolutions and vice-versa. How can I do this ?